# Jquery not working with loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery .load to load content into my page which works fine, but my ellipsis jQuery library no long works for the loaded content. The ellipsis JQuery added '...' at the end of my paragraph, but no longer works because it is now loaded content.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.article1 p').ellipsis();   // worked before using .load
       $(".article1").load("/inc/latest-articles.asp #article1");    
   });
</script>
```

Is there a trick I'm missing? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the document first so that `$('.article1 p')` isn't empty when you call your plugin :

```
$(".article1").load("/inc/latest-articles.asp #article1", function(){
   $('.article1 p').ellipsis();   
});
```